# Which of the following cannot be the class equation of a group G of order 10?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Which of the following cannot be the class equation of a group G of order 10?

1)1+1+1+2+5.

2)1+2+3+4.

3)1+2+2+5.

4)1+1+2+2+2+2.

**Reasoning**

(1) is not the required class equation because if it is then the order of centre of G will be not possible due to Lagrange's theorem.

(4) is not the class equation because if it is so then the index of centre of G
 in G will be 2 which implies G to be abelian leading to the class equation 10.Which is not possible.

**In answer key correct options are (1),(2),(4)**.I'm not getting why (2) is not the class equation.

In my class notes it is told that $S_3$ is the largest group with each conjugacy class of distict sizes.But,G is a group of order 10 with each conjugacy class of distict size in (2).

Is there any other reason why (2) is not the class equation?

Comment: There are only two isomorphism classes of order 10 groups: cyclic and dihedral.

Comment: Maybe because $3$ does not divide $10$? Every class must have a divisor of $|G|$ elements.

Comment: @Crostul:Got it!!You're correct

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:I forgot this point.Thanks for making me remember.

Answer (score 2):

1+2+3+4 means
there are four distinct conjugate classes having order 1,2,3 & 4.
Since, |cl(a)|.|N(a)|=|G|,
then for class of order 3,
3.|N(a)|=10.
But 10 is not multiple of 3.Hence the class equation is not possible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).